# Linear regression is wrong?

Tags: regression

I tried asking this in electronics as a question related to oscillators, but I wasn't able to get a satisfactory answer.  I think the more math-y types here may shed some additional light on the phenomenon I am observing.

I am using two clocks (measured-clock and reference-clock) to measure the time of one relative to the other.  I plot the accumulated difference between the clocks (in microseconds) vs. the total time elapsed on the reference-clock (in seconds).  After collecting an hours' worth of data, I can perform a linear regression to determine the difference in frequency between the clocks.

The linear regression has $r^2 = 0.9999$, so it's about as perfect as you can get.  The slope of the line is, for example, $-36.3$.  This implies that for every second of reference-clock time, the measured-clock falls 36.3 microseconds behind.

I then tune the measured-clock so that it has an extra 36.3 microseconds per second.  I then re-run my analysis, expecting a very flat slope and poor $r^2$.  Instead, I get another $r^2 = 0.9999$, with a slope of about $-1.2$.  If I adjust for an *additional* 1.2 us/s (bringing the total to 37.5 us/s), I then get the satisfactory "flat slope and poor $r^2$".

It appears as if the first linear regression was wrong, despite the perfect $r^2$.  Iteratively calculating linear regressions while $r^2$ is very high will arrive at the correct answer, so it seems as if there is some systemic error that I am unaware of.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My initial clock frequency estimate is 14,318,180 Hz (the HPET timer).  From iterative regressions, I can determine that the real clock frequency should be 14,318,712 Hz.  This is an additional 532 ticks per second, which implies that the actual error is $-37.156$ us/s.

Here is the initial regression.  The X axis is the elapsed time of the reference clock, **in seconds**.  The Y axis is the difference between the elapsed time on the measured clock and the elapsed time on the reference clock, **in microseconds** (i.e. the error between the two clocks as a function of the elapsed time on the reference clock).  The reference clock is precise, but not accurate, however I want to match any inaccuracy in the reference clock so that's okay.
[image]

Here is a plot of the residuals for that regression.  [image]

The initial regression suggests an error of $-36.054$ us/s.  This is an additional 516 ticks per second, suggesting that my HPET is really $14,318,696$ Hz.  As mentioned above, however, this value is not correct.

Comment: What variables is the linear regression relating? You might have them in the wrong order.

Comment: Having a Pearson correlation coefficient near 1 isn't always a guarantee for linear behavior; it only says that linear behavior is "very likely". Did you remember to plot residuals?

Comment: I have updated the question with plots of the regression and residuals.

Comment: Ah, you see the curving up in your residuals? That's what Ralph was alluding to in his answer.

Comment: I believe the curving that you allude to is subtle (like 0.05 PPM) changes in the test oscillator's frequency.  The curve is not a pure U, but more of a wavey W.

Comment: If necessary, you could cut the analysis short at the 3000 second mark.  The result is still the same; -36 us/s regression, and the remaining residuals would not have any curvy shape, though they would resemble a slowly increasing line

Comment: Where you wrote "us/s", did you mean "$\mu s/s$"?

Answer (score 3):

You are violating the *independence* assumption of linear regression.  Your observations are correlated with each other. You cannot use standard linear regression.

Comment: I'm not sure how they're correlated?  They are two independently free-running oscillators.  If standard linear regression is not correct, then what analysis should I run instead?

Comment: @ajs - The problem is not the correlation between the oscillators. It is an autocorrellation problem within the data.  If I pick any two people born in 2000 and correlate their weights with each other for each year 2000-2011, there is most likely going to be a significant correlation.

Comment: Okay, even if I ignore linear regression and instead choose to use a point-slope calculation, the result I get is still erroneous.  And yet the relationship is pretty clearly linear, because once I know the "right" slope everything works fine.  But the techniques I'm using do not give me the right slope on the first try.

Comment: If errors are correlated and their covariance matrix is $\sigma^2 V$ where $V$ is a known matrix and $\sigma>0$ must be estimated based on the data, then instead of minimizing $\|\hat\varepsilon\|^2$, the sum of squares of residuals, one should minimize $\hat\varepsilon^T V^{-1}\hat\varepsilon$ where $\hat\varepsilon$ is the vector of residuals.